# What's the LINQ equivalent to SUM(CASE WHEN X=Y THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)?

Tags: vb.net, linq-to-sql

Not sure if this is just a bad habit, or a valid way of doing things, but for large complex report queries spanning bunches of tables, I often get my aggregate stats by summing a `Case` statement.

For example:

```
SELECT Contact.Name,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Order.Type = 'Special' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS SpecialOrders,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Order.Type = 'Magic' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS MagicOrders,
FROM Contact
LEFT JOIN Order ON (Contact.ContactID = Order.ContactID)
```

How would I do this in LINQ to SQL? (In vb.net, but I guess any .Net example would do)

```
Dim Orders = _
    From Order In DB.Orders
    Select New With {.Name = Contact.Name, 
                     .Special = If(Order.Type = "Special", 1, 0),
                     .Magical = If(Order.Type = "Magical ", 1, 0)}
```

I need to sum the `.Special` and `.Magical` values.

*(In reality, the query spans several tables consisting of event-booking information, and the decision to sum a record or not depends on fields in several of them)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var specialSum = DB.Orders.Sum (o => o.Type == "Special" ? 1 : 0)
var magicalSum = DB.Orders.Sum (o => o.Type == "Magical" ? 1 : 0)
```

Or:

```
var specialSum = DB.Orders.Count (o => o.Type == "Special")
var magicalSum = DB.Orders.Count (o => o.Type == "Magical")
```

Comment: That's C#, OP is looking for the VB.Net equivalent.

Comment: "In vb.net, but I guess any .Net example would do" - that's what he said. I'm afraid I don't speak VB.

Comment: Additionally, this does not perform the join that OP's sql query does.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend the first answer

```
    var specialSum = DB.Orders.Sum (o => o.Type == "Special" ? 1 : 0)
    var magicalSum = DB.Orders.Sum (o => o.Type == "Magical" ? 1 : 0)
```

The second answer is much slower. I dont know why, but it was much slower according to my tests.